# UltraEdit - regular expressions replacement

Tags: regular-expression

I was trying many different combinations without success, at this point I would be really grateful for your help.

I need to replace this end of the line multiple times (around 300) and it would be painful to replace it one by one:

```
:;XXXXXX (lenght may vary)
```

I was able to find it with `:;*$` which highlights exactly what I need!
But I'm unable to replace it, to make it look like this: `:;XXXXXX;;;`

`*` - is supposed to match anything (and it does)

`$` - is supposed to match end of the line (and it does)

I've tried encapsulating `*` in brackets `(*); [*]`...like `:;(*);;;$` among other things, but to no avail. Of course replacement is made, but in the same form as input. For example... instead of `:;XXXXXX;;;` I get `:;*;;;` - and that is the best I was able to get out of it.

This is UltraEdit regular expression format, but this piece of software can process Unix and Perl regular expressions as well.

I you can suggest ANY way to do this, I will give it a try (terminal, another software etc.).

**EDIT:**

I'm trying to get contacts from old nokia to newer nokia (s30+ series). There was only backup.nbu from which I got .vcf contacts. I have put them to one file via `cat *.vcf > combined.vcf`. I've found Excel macro and PHP script which were supposed to do the whole process, but they didn'work - but all this is not that relevant I guess. After that I have found Vcard format this particular model can process. Now I'm trying to modify it, to look the same. Replacing lines was no problem, but I need to edit ends. `;:NAME` to `;:NAME;;;` without modifying names...

I tried what I've described above. After that I've tried suggested `sed -ri "s/\:\;X+$/&\;\;\;/g"`.

I tough that DOS ends of the lines might be the problem, so I ran:`sed -i 's/\r//g' combined.vcf` and then again the suggested sid command.

FROM: `N;CHARSET=UTF-8;ENCODING=8BIT:ALFA`

TO: `N;ENCODING=QUOTED-PRINTABLE;CHARSET=UTF-8:;ALFA;;;`

**EDIT2:**

*So I went from the beginning...*

1. I've combined .vcf files
2. Opened them in UltraEdit and saved as LF (from CRLF) - tried this time without `sed` and terminal
3. In find replace I've selected Perl Regex

   - Find `(:;)(.*)`
   - Replace `\1\2;;;`

For reference: `.*` - Match zero or more of any characters (except new line)...

**DONE!**

Comment: Congrats on solving your issue, but we don't use SOLVED on this site, mark the answer that solves/answers your question as the answer and use the votes when you have the rep. I believe SOLVED is used on forums so I understand where you have it from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is called the back-references. It means "*put here whatever was selected in the match*" and functions by:

1. Using parenthesis in the matching regex to select a part of the string,
2. Using a numbered back-reference (`\1` for the first parenthesis, `\2` for the second one, etc.).

`sed` support this and this produces the following command (`sed` requires the parenthesis to be escaped, but this may not be the case for other regex based software):

```
sed -i 's/^\(:;.*\)$/\1;;;/' combined.vcf
```

Comment: Selected for getting me on track with back-reference!!! Thank you mate! I will provide solution in my question...

Answer (score 0):

Using `sed` this can done like this:

```
echo ":;XXXXXX" | sed -re "s/\:\;X+$/&\;\;\;/g"
```

As you are taking the data from some file, you can directly edit it inside file using:

```
sed -ri "s/\:\;X+$/&\;\;\;/g" file.txt
```

Comment: It didn't work for me :/. I will provide more info in my question asap!